# How to access nodes of decision tree built using mllib in pyspark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree, py4j

My code is
   `from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree,DecisionTreeModel`

`model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(training_data)`

`Node = model.call("topNode")`

```
#To access top node
tNode = model.call("topNode")
#For left node 
lNode = tNode.leftNode()
```

But I think there is no method for accessing leftNode/rightNode of any node except rootNode/topNode. 
I am also trying to use py4j library to access java objects in python.
Thanks